# How do you make sure WPF releases large BitmapSource from Memory?

Tags: wpf, memory-leaks, bitmap, bitmapsource

System:  Windows XP SP3, .NET 3.5, 4GB RAM, Dual 1.6gHz

I have a WPF application that loads and transitions (using Storyboard animations) extremely large PNGs. These PNGs are 8190x1080 in resolution. As the application runs it appears to cache the images and the system Memory slowly creeps up. Eventually it chokes the system and throws the OutOfMemoryException.

Here are the steps I am currently taking to try to solve this:

1)I am removing the BitmapSource objects from the app

2)I am setting the BitmapSource BitmapCacheOption to None when I load the BitmapSource

3)I am Freezing the  BitmapSource once it's loaded.

4)I am  deleting all references to the Image  that uses the source as well as any references to the source itself.

5)Manually calling GC.Collect() after above steps have completed.

Hoping to figure out why WPF is hanging onto memory for these images and a possible solution to ensure that the memory used to load them is properly recovered.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You certainly have put in a lot of work on this.  I think the main problem is that BitmapCacheOption.None doesn't prevent the underlying BitmapDecoder(s) from being cached.

There are several tricky solutions to this such as doing a GC.Collect(), loading 300 small images from 300 different Uris, and calling GC.Collect() again, but the simple one is straightforward:

Instead of loading from a Uri, just construct a Stream and pass it to BitmapFrame's constructor:

```
var source = new BitmapImage();
using(Stream stream = ...)
{
  source.BeginInit();
  source.StreamSource = stream;
  source.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;    // not a mistake - see below
  source.EndInit();
}
```

The reason this should work is that loading from a stream completely disables the cache.  Not only is the top-level source not cached, but none of the internal decoders are cached either.

Why BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad?  It seems counterintuitive, but this flag has two effects:  It enables caching if caching is possible, and it causes the load to happen at EndInit().  In our case caching is impossible, so all it does it cause the load to happen immediately.

Obviously you'll want to run this code off your UI thread, then freeze the BitmapSource so you can move it over.

You may also wonder why I didn't use BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache.  Other than the fact that caching is impossible any with no URI given, the IgnoreImageCache doesn't completely ignore the image cache:  It only ignores it for reading.  So even if IgnoreImageCache is set, the loaded image is still inserted into the cache.  The difference is that the existing image in the cache is ignored.

Comment: BitmapSource source = new BitmapSource() won't compile and I'm not sure why. Throws this error: 
Error 4 Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource'

Comment: Ahh..it compiles when I use BitmapImage instead of BitmapSource.

Now, how will that cause problems? :)

Comment: This approach looks promising so far. I'll continue to test.

Comment: @RayBurns : Please verify this post.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872636/out-of-memory-exception-while-printing-in-wpf
I tried your way..... get new exception

Comment: For anyone wondering what `...` should be, if you are trying to load an image off the local disk, try `new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open)`.

Comment: _just construct a Stream and pass it to **BitmapFrame's** constructor_ @RayBurns, what does it mean?